# How to customize fullcalendar day style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, fullcalendar

I need to be able to expand the event displayed on the fullcalendar when I mouse over it. Event should be displayed with ellipsis. The event should be fully displayed when I hover over it. I need this for angular app.

How can this be done?
thanks

Comment: Can you show us what have you attempted to do or part of your code?

Comment: Rather than expand the event, it's quite easy to make a popover which appears when hovering over the event. In fact I'm pretty sure there's a demo of it in the documentation already.

Comment: Yes. Fullcalendar can display tooltip on mouseover https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo but I need to expand the event rather then show tool tip. Can this be done?

Comment: Also, can I include ellipsis, links, image into the event displayed in the calendar?

Comment: "I need to expand the event"...why, specifically? What's wrong with the tooltip? That's a much easier solution and provides basically the same experience for the user. However you probably _can_ expand the event - just use Javascript to change CSS attributes of the element - e.g. size or it's top/bottom, or maybe its overflow setting. Did you try any of those?

Comment: And yes you can include any content you want into the element. If you don't want it there from when the event is first shown, you can use JavaScript to dynamically add items to the element when the hover event happens. None of that is specific to fullCalendar, it's just how you can manipulate any HTML element in any web page.

Comment: If you want to add anything up-front, like the ellipsis you mentioned, in the latest fullCalendar you can use the event render hooks mentioned in the documentation. (In earlier versions, since you didn't mention your version, there's the single eventRender callback.). I don't think the fact you're using Angular is necessarily relevant, unless you want to use some more Angular-style conventions to manipulate the element...but I don't use Angular so I can't advise on the specifics of that. It's certainly all feasible using regular JS though. And within Angular you can still use that.

Comment: Thanks to your help I was able to implement expansion of the event with ellipsis. I am not against tooltip  but my job was to test some features that included event expansion.

Comment: I have another question. We are testing the level of customization that is possible in the calendar. As a part of this test I want to be able to insert an angular component into a calendar cell. Is it possible? How this can be done? thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about Angular or what constitutes a "component" in its terminology. But if it's something whose end result is to display some HTML, then in theory I don't see why not. Anyway though if you have a new, distinct question, please create a new stackoverflow question and give it suitable tags, show an example of what you mean, etc. and hopefully people with Angular experience will see it. They certainly won't see it buried in these comments though.... :-)